# How to add object level permission in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a `Building` model and in that i have a field `notes` which has `GenericRelation` to `GeneralNote`. In `Building` admin added `GeneralNotes` as Inlines. Now I want that the `GeneralNotes` is editable for the user who is owner of general note.

```py
class Building(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(                                                               unique=True, max_length=100, verbose_name=_("Building Name"), help_text=_("This is the name of your building")
    ) 
    notes = GenericRelation(GeneralNote)



class GeneralNote(TimeStampedModel):                                                           

    owner = models.ForeignKey(                                              
            CompanyEmployee,                                                    
            blank=True,                                                         
            null=True,                                                          
            # related_name='noteOwner',                                         
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,                                          
            verbose_name="Note Owner",                                          
    )                                                                       

    content = models.TextField(max_length=400, null=True )                  
    date_of_action = models.DateField(null=True)                            
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()                               
    attached_to = GenericForeignKey()
```

In `admin.py`:

```py
class BuildingAdmin(ImportMixin, GeneralNotesIncludedAdmin):
    inlines = (GeneralNoteInLine,)


class GeneralNotesIncludedAdmin(CoreBaseAdmin):                                                

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):                                    
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)                                                 

        for instance in instances:                                                             
            if not instance.owner:                                                             
                instance.owner = request.user.companyemployee                                  
            instance.save()                                                                    

        super().save_formset(request, form, formset, change)


class CoreBaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                                         
    save_on_top = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) method:

```
class GeneralNotesIncludedAdmin(CoreBaseAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user.companyemployee
```

You can also add these to [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.has_change_permission):

```
class GeneralNoteInLine(InlineModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user.companyemployee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and use guardian [admin integration](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/admin-integration.html).